# I have a flash drive and I want to compile everywhere

Tags: c++, windows, vim, mingw, portability

I came from gnu/linux world but recently I must to work on a **windows** system and I want to be able to compile my **c/c++** console programs on it. The problem is I don't have administrative privilegies to install anything.
I looked for **portable** apps. I'd find gvim and mingw but I don't know how to make them work together on a flash drive. I'd found also a vim plugin called msysportable that's supposed to do the job but I don't know how.

So my question is: how can I make a portable windows c/c++ development environment using gvim?
(don't tell me to use code::blocks or visual studio, I've this installed but I want **vim**)

Comment: Doesn't `:let $PATH='E:\MinGW\Bin;'.$PATH` in the `vimrc` help?

Comment: Z:\Tools\msys\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c "gcc"
File not found

Comment: Suggestion, once you get the other stuff figured out: make sure you don't compile+link *to* the flashdrive, it's going to be unbearably slow and wear out the erase cycles. If you want to be über-portable, you can make your build scripts output somewhere under %temp% .

Comment: interesting snemarch, i didn't think about cycles..

Answer (score 0):

copy your development environment to your flash-drive. Create a batch file to setup environment variables for paths to include dirs ,lib dirs ,executables ,etc. Then use this environment in cmd session with console commands. If you have installed MSVC on your own system then there is a batch-file called vcdirs.bat thar does this on youre system, Take it as example how to make a portable environment. By the way ,INSTALLING youre tools at a vlient-site may be a license violation. The portable environment is not as long as you do not install it.

Comment: i've founded mobaxterm, check it is awesome